# Как кроссбраузерно разделить div на 9 равных дивов?(3х3)

Tags: css, вёрстка, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы, чтобы вы поделились своими рецептами кроссбраузерного(ie8+) деления дива на 3х3 только в процентах и только на дивы. Запрещается использовать адаптивные фреймворки и флексы.

```css
.table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  font-size: 0;
  }

.table div {
    width: 33.33333333333333333333%;
    height: 33.3333333333333333333%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>

<div class="social">
<a href="" target="blank"><div><i class="icon-vkontakte"></i></div></a>
<a href="" target="blank"><div><i class="icon-facebook"></i></div></a>
<a href="" target="blank"><div><i class="icon-github-circled"></i></div></a>
<a href="" target="blank"><div><i class="icon-linkedin-squared"></i></div></a>
</div>
```

На всех браузерах отображается корректно, но для Safari нужно прописывать в .table display: table. А Firefox не отображает все корректно.

Comment: вставить в него таблицу 3х3

Comment: Изменил вопрос, нужно поделить див на дивы

Comment: Укажите насколько кроссбраузерно? IE5 may be?

Comment: Нужно чтобы поддерживал ie8+

Comment: А как Вы попытались решить эту задачку? Тут всё-таки помощь, а не free freelance.

Comment: Изменил в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сноси `font-size` и делай [по-человечески](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px dotted green;
}

.table div {
  width: 33.33333333333333333333%;
  height: 33.3333333333333333333%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div>
    Вставить
  </div><div>
    содержимое
  </div><div>
    легко
  </div><div>
    просто
  </div><div>
    не
  </div><div>
    надо
  </div><div>
    трогать
  </div><div>
    сочетание
  </div><div>
    &lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.icon-vkontakte { background-image: url(//vk.com/favicon.ico); }
.icon-facebook { background-image: url(//www.facebook.com/favicon.ico); }
.icon-github-circled { background-image: url(//github.com/favicon.ico); }
.icon-linkedin-squared { background-image: url(//ru.linkedin.com/favicon.ico); }

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

a:hover {
  background: silver;
}

html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <a href="http://vk.com" target="blank">
    <div><i class="icon-vkontakte"></i></div>
  </a><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="blank">
    <div><i class="icon-facebook"></i></div>
  </a><a href="https://github.com" target="blank">
    <div><i class="icon-github-circled"></i></div>
  </a><a href="https://ru.linkedin.com" target="blank">
    <div><i class="icon-linkedin-squared"></i></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Слушай, объясни пожалуйста, в чем фишка тут? Почему 8 блоков обернуты в 1 и отображается 9 блоков? Не укладывается в голове

Comment: @АлексейКраснов, обёрнуты 9 блоков, как было у тебя. Я просто переносы строк переставил, чтобы пробелы убрать. По ссылке посмотри про пробелы между inline-блоками. Ну и vertical-align top устраняет расстояние между base-line и низом строки.

Comment: Слушай, а как вставить в каждый див по элементу, допустим еще 1 див , не нарушая конструкцию, чтобы не появились пробелы?

Comment: @АлексейКраснов, легко. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Слушай, тут такой вопрос появился. В общем при входе на сайт через мобилу эти блоки встают в display: block и width:100%. Все работает хорошо, только вот в самом низу остается под последнем блоком есть пустое место небольшое, я как понял это тот самый промежуток, от которого я избавлялся. Как его убрать?

Comment: @АлексейКраснов, похоже, это погрешность округления. Высота не делится на 3. Если в моём примере поставить `height: 302px`, то всё ровно.

Comment: А если в процентах? Нужны резиновые блоки)

Comment: @АлексейКраснов, блоки вполне резиновые. Нужно чтобы 100% в пикселях делилось на 3. Иначе хром оставляет снизу пространство. По крайней мере, очень похоже, что так.

Comment: слушай, у меня есть блок, который должен делится на 4 части равные. Но там wrappers в виду <a>. Можно как то так же сделать? Делаю по аналогии. не выходит(это для сафари) Я добавил в вопрос блок внизу.

Comment: Просто супер, спасибо огромное, ты мне очень сильно помог, просто описать нельзя как помог, если нужна помощь, обращайся!) vk.com/worddoc

Answer (score 0):

Нет IE8 под рукой, но должно работать и там:

```css
.table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```